# Way to use a screen in a dark environment

Tags: javascript, html, screen, brightness

Im looking for the name of a technique so I can use my web browser in a darker environment. I want to create a web application that would allow the screen to be visible but without glaring too bright so I cant see other things in the dark

I know this technique is used in `Stellarium` as '*night mode* which gives the screen a reddish sort of tint and decreased brightness but It would let me look at my pc and observe the sky without being too bright so my eyes would still let me see things in the dark?

Any hints on what this technique is called?/Ways to do this in html/js

Comment: Probably [Purkinje effect](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Purkinje_effect) -- which is why _night mode_ is so much more common... Or maybe [Scotopic vision](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scotopic_vision).

Comment: [Flux](http://stereopsis.com/flux/) describes it as a warming effect (simply a change in the color temperature of your screen).

Comment: I think you should put a lot of black and grey for the background. And white for the texts, and the things you want to emphasize on. (Take iBooks's night mode as an example : http://www.google.fr/search?q=ibooks+night+view&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla:fr:official&client=firefox-a&um=1&ie=UTF-8&hl=fr&tbm=isch&source=og&sa=N&tab=wi&ei=lRPvT7PuOoSX0QXmhpXlDQ&biw=1280&bih=666&sei=lxPvT_b1HpKS8gOzi-m5DQ).

Comment: I like how Flux does it, but its a whole computer way. I'd really just like it to be in the web browser. White for the text is still very bright, but perhaps grey might work, is there no framework out there designed for this?

Answer (score 0):

Determine the users' whereabouts and/or time based on their IP address with the [Geolocation API](http://dev.w3.org/geo/api/spec-source.html) or [getTimezoneOffset](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_gettimezoneoffset.asp) and then provide differrent styles based on the time of day.

Comment: This answer is orthogonal to tthe question.  The OP wants to know *what kinds* of styles to apply, not *when* to apply them.

Comment: The question being: "_Any hints on what this technique is called?/Ways to do this in html/js_"

I don't know the name of the technique but have recommended two ways to do it.